# How to set different destinations in nodejs using multer base on user choice

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am trying to build an app that the user will choose a category and upload an image to the different folder based on the category that they choose.

I have seen some posts about set differernt destinations in nodejs using multer, but if I want to pass another string in the request which is the category. Should I just send another POST request with the category? Im kinda lost.

Comment: You'll like have to manually move the file to the desired location once it has been uploaded to a temporary location on your server.

Comment: What I have done for my problem is that I send the category information in the header of the request